# Alamofire hit twice server with Xcode 7.3 and it's recomnded swift version

Tags: ios, networking

I have the xcode 7.3 and I am using the Swift for development. I am using the alamofire for the networking but, it gets problematic. It hits the API twice.

Comment: Re check your code...or please post some code so we can see if something wrong with it

Comment: Alamofire doesn't give this problem. There must be something in your code due to which APIs are hit twice. Please write the code here. So that we can replicate the issue.